# Writing a custom ngrx operator and returning the source observable type

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, oftype

I have a custom operator, `waitFor` which I am using in my effects as so:

```
public effect$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(myAction),
      waitFor<ReturnType<typeof myAction>>([anotherAction]),
      ...etc
    );
  });
```

It basically looks at correlationId's to not continue executing until the array of actions have been dispatched. But that is beside the point here.

As expected `ofType` takes the source observable and uses this as the return type, however I am struggling to achieve the same effect. As you can see above I am using `ReturnType<typeof myAction>>` and the following in my `waitFor` method:

```
export function waitFor<A extends Action>(actionsToWaitFor$: Array<Actions>): OperatorFunction<A, A> {
```

So at the moment if I call `waitFor` like this:

```
public effect$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(myAction),
      waitFor([anotherAction]),
      ...etc
    );
  });
```

Then its type is inferred as `Action`, but I want this to be `ReturnType<typeof theSourceObservable>` by default. So I would assume I would need something like this in my `waitFor` method:

```
export function waitFor<A extends ReturnType<typeof sourceObservable?!>>(actionsToWaitFor$: Array<Actions>): OperatorFunction<A, A> {
```

`waitFor` looks like this:

```
export function waitFor<A extends Action>(actionsToWaitFor$: Array<Actions>): OperatorFunction<A, A> {
  return (source$) => {
    return source$.pipe(
      switchMap((action: A & { correlationId: string}) => {
        // use zip() to wait for all actions 
        // and when omitting map((action) => action)
        // so the original action is always returned
      })
    );
  };
}
```

From the `ofType` [source](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/actions.ts#L63), it looks like I need to use `Extract`

### Update

StackBlitz example is shown [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ujmnw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.service.ts)

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and expected result / behavior ?

Comment: @DanieleRicci, how's [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ujmnw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.service.ts) for an example. Make sure you are looking at `example.service.ts`. I am only concerned about the returned types, so you don't need to run anything but just read that file. Thanks for your help

Comment: It is not clear why you are focusing on that. I think the return type is not a requirement for you. Which target do you want to achieve? It could be it can be achieved some other way....

Comment: I agree. Assuming use of `ReturnType` is assuming the form of the solution where it's probably not necessary.

Comment: @DanieleRicci - Sorry I mean I am focusing on the return type of the custom operator, not specifically the use of `ReturnType`. eg. in the example `private thisWontWork(): OperatorFunction<ANYTHINGTOMAKEITWORK>`. Is what I am looking to achieve. By "work" I mean that the correct type is inferred from the source observable.

Take a look at how ngrx does it with `ofType` [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/actions.ts#L29-L107). Like `ofType` I can also safely assume that that source observable will be an `Action`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This, at least, compiles; I don't know if it also does what you need.

```
public effect3$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => {
  const a:Action[]= []

  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(doSomething),
    this.someCustomOperatorReturningStaticTypes(),
    this.thisWontWork(a),
    tap(({aCustomProperty}) => {
      // The type is inferred
      console.log(aCustomProperty);
    }),
  )
});

private thisWontWork<A extends Action>(actionsToWaitFor$: Action[]): OperatorFunction<A, A> {
  return (source$) => {
    return source$.pipe(
      tap(() => {
        console.log('Should work')
      })
    )
  }
}
```

I wasn't able to run it in the StackBlitz, any hint?

Hope this helps

Comment: I was sure I tried this! haha. Thanks for your help. I am still not sure how A gets its type from `doSomething`

Comment: Here is the StackBlitz of the above https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ibfef?file=src/app/example.service.ts

Answer (score 2):

Came across this question and I thought I'd add a couple explanations in case you are still wondering and if anyone comes across this in future!

#### First - in your example you're overthinking it in terms of the return type.

If you want to infer something as the type it is passed as (e.g here you want your action to be returned as the type it is) you just return the same generic which you pass in - as the answer says like:

```js
function foo<A>(val: A): A {
  return val;
}
```

If I call foo() with a number, I get a number back. If I call it with a specific action type, then the same thing happens. This is why you just need the return `type OperatorFunction<A, A>` - same thing in, same thing out.

#### Second - how does ofType work?

The key here is that you need some set of actions which you are narrowing.

Using createAction takes care of this for you, but for example's sake I'll create this by hand.

```js
type FooAction = { type: 'FOO_ACTION' };
type BarAction = { type: 'BAR_ACTION' };

// This type gets built by you using createAction - this is your Action type
type MyActions = FooAction | BarAction;
```

Next we need a type which is going to take our set of actions (`MyActions`) - and narrow it to a specific action based on the type.

```js
type NarrowActionType<T extends { type: any }, K extends string> = T extends { type: K }
  ? T
  : never;
```

We can verify this works:

```js
type NarrowedActionTest = NarrowActionType<MyActions, 'FOO_ACTION'>;
```

[image: Verifying NarrowedActionTest works in TS playground]

ofType is a higher order function which first accepts a string, and then the observable stream to operate on. I'm not going to use observables to keep it simpler, but it's the same principle.

In essence we want something along the lines of `(type: string) => (action: Action) => action is NarrowActionType` for the type signature.

- NarrowActionType needs the overall action type as it's first type parameter, which we will call `A`
- NarrowActionType needs the string literal type which we are using to narrow with, which we will call `T`
- T is going to be a string, so `T` extends string
- We only know the type of `T` to begin with, and then the type of `A` once the object stream is applied, so let's use one generic parameter at each function application
- The function is going to ultimately check if `A.type` is the same as type. So we should enforce this exists, with `A extends { type: any }`

```js
function isOfType<T extends string>(type: T) {
    return <A extends { type: any }>(action: A): action is NarrowActionType<A, T> => {
        return action.type === type
    }
}
```

Now we can test this function on a MyActions type, and see if it can narrow the output:

```js
const myAction: MyActions = { type: 'FOO_ACTION' };
const isFooAction = isOfType('FOO_ACTION')(myAction);

if (isOfType('FOO_ACTION')(myAction)) {
    type myNarrowedAction = typeof myAction; // is FooAction
}
```

Full playground link here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-Dg9oPE5BAlEkg0pG+6poxk0p0nRnfHCYqA0qPEiCxn0omphJMp8WM5na3UWqBOxVoIERjQGZCZ0tylxQJpQPbh8UmUxAA

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)